# Is my iPython Installation Valid?

Tags: data-science-model, numpy, plotting, matplotlib, ipython

I just want to know if my ipython is properly installed. I have both Python and Anaconda installed on my Windows. I entered the "pip3 install ipython" command on the Command Prompt and it downloaded and installed the ipython package. However, whenever I try to access it, I see this:

[image]

Notice the icon on the top left hand corner:

[image]

And whenever I execute a code and will like to continue working in that file, it will take forever for iPython to take me to the next line of code (or in some cases, may not even do so). For example, in the case below, I have not been able to enter any code after the "In [18]: plt.show()" since "In [19]:" would not just come up. Please see this:

[image]

I believe this is because the package is not properly installed.

I will be grateful if you guys can just show me what I can do about this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks fine to me :)  the only problem is that your plot (resulting from `In [18]`) is being displayed on your computer in a separate window somewhere - maybe you have to find it. Once you close that window, your iPython prompt woill return to `In [19]`. You could alternatively press `Ctrl-C` in the iPython session, but this will end the session.

If the problem persists (and you cannot even find/close the plot from `plt.show()`) - maybe have a [look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108696/cannot-manually-close-matplotlib-plot-window), which discusses the various backends used for matplotlib.

I assume you do this to begin with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

`plt` is a module (as the error message says), so you cannot use it directly like that, but rather the functions that are contained in that module, like `scatter()` (which worked for you) and then others like `plot()`, `hist()` and so on.

Have a look at [**the relevant documentation**](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html) with lots of exmaples.

Here is a full example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# evenly sampled time at 200ms intervals
t = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)

# red dashes, blue squares and green triangles
plt.plot(t, t, 'r--', t, t**2, 'bs', t, t**3, 'g^')
plt.show()
```

[image]